# init.d script for SeleniumGrid under CentOS 5.5

Tags: java, centos, centos5, selenium-grid, init.d

I'm establishing Continuous Integration environment for our team. And part of that environment is Selenium Grid running under the CentOS 5.5. I ran into a problem, i can't set up an autostartup for SeleniumGrid with a system.

I've tried to write init.d script, but with lacking of bash scripting knowledge it wasn't successful undertaking. Googling wasn't successful either, but i've found solution for debian systems [here](https://gist.github.com/816876).

So, could someone plz point me at solution for centos or give me advise how to write the init.d script?

Comment: This might help: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/using-debian-start-stop-daemon-on-centos-680223/

Comment: Thank you for reply! I'll try to convert that script.

Answer (score 4):

I've written that script. It works for me and can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/838591)
Comments and requests are welcome =)